# Selenium webdriver permission problem in linux persists

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver

I would like to see the capabilities of selenium which is controlled by a python script. I downloaded the geckodriver executable and put it in some directory. I use a linux and I try run the below code through a virtualenv:

```
from selenium import webdriver
path = '/home/devel-20/Desktop/devel/programs'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devel-20/Desktop/devel/virtualenvs/restaurant/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/devel-20/Desktop/devel/programs'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devel-20/Desktop/devel/projects/r/shop/selenium_tests", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)
  File "/home/devel-20/Desktop/devel/virtualenvs/restaurant/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/devel-20/Desktop/devel/virtualenvs/restaurant/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'programs' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

I'm confused because I'm running this with a user called "devel-20". This is the permissions of the programs directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x 4 devel-20 devel-20 4096 Sep 27 07:04 programs/
```

And this is the permissions of the geckodriver file:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 devel-20 devel-20 12184306 Sep 16 01:48 geckodriver*
```

I don't understand why this permissions problem persists.

Could you give me some guidance?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` you're referring to is not right. It should denote the geckodriver binary to use for Firefox.

An alternative approach, considering your firefox installation path is this one:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. It works fine now, using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary)
```

However, I added "geckodriver" to the following folder:

```
/home/devel-20/Desktop/virtualenvs/restaurant/bin
```

This folder is in $PATH in this virtualenv. If not added to a folder which the local $PATH knows about, there will be the well-known selenium/geckodriver PATH problem.